# errors when trying extract package name from Class variable

Tags: java, class, reflection, package

In my current project, i have this code:

```
    for(Annotation annotation : field.getAnnotations()) {
      String package = annotation.annotationType().getPackage().getName();
      if(package.equals("com.loja.annotations.input_type"))
        input.setAttribute("type", annotation.annotationType().getSimpleName());
    }
```

when i try build the project, this code causes a compilation failure due to this error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project store: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Kleber Mota/Documents/GitHub/app/src/main/java/com/loja/thymeleaf/processor/form/InputProcessor.java:[37,11] not a statement
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Kleber Mota/Documents/GitHub/app/src/main/java/com/loja/thymeleaf/processor/form/InputProcessor.java:[37,17] ';' expected
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Kleber Mota/Documents/GitHub/app/src/main/java/com/loja/thymeleaf/processor/form/InputProcessor.java:[38,14] illegal start of expression
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Kleber Mota/Documents/GitHub/app/src/main/java/com/loja/thymeleaf/processor/form/InputProcessor.java:[38,21] illegal start of expression
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Kleber Mota/Documents/GitHub/app/src/main/java/com/loja/thymeleaf/processor/form/InputProcessor.java:[38,28] ';' expected
[ERROR] /c:/Users/Kleber Mota/Documents/GitHub/app/src/main/java/com/loja/thymeleaf/processor/form/InputProcessor.java:[38,22] variable declaration not allowed here
```

anyone can see what's wrong here?

line 37 is: `String package = annotation.annotationType().getPackage().getName();` and line 38 is `if(package.equals("com.loja.annotations.input_type"))`

Comment: You can’t name a variable `package` as that’s a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this..

```
annotation.annotationType().getName();
```

Comment: but i need the package for the annotation class, not the annotation name.

Answer (score 0):

You can print out your "package" variable after line 37 (before if). 
I wrote and ran the similar code and it worked for me. I created a custom annotation in my api package and line 37 returned "api".

Comment: I change the name of the variable and work for me. I just realize `package` is a reserved word in Java. i think that was the problem.

Comment: oo yes :) I changed that as well but thought your IDE would already have warned you.